# How to setup cells in a static table divided in sections programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm basically making a settings view on my app and I'm using a static table for it. So I divided the table into 3 sections each with one cell. Not programmatically I can easily label each cell and it works but programmatically I'm not able to initialize each cell. I can only initialize the first cell that gets repeated across the 3 sections. I would like a way to initialize a cell for each section but I can't find a method or a way to do that. My tableview also has reuseIdentifiers but it doesn't seem like the UITableViewController recognizes it.

This is what I have done so far.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EditProfile";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = nil; //[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // More initializations if needed.
    }
    //Observations *currentList = [self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hey";
    //return cell;

    return cell;
}
```

But what I want is the cell in the first section to be labeled: Edit Profile, the second one: Invite and the third:Logout

Comment: It would make more sense to do it entirely in interface builder, if you are making static cells. You dont have to write a single code to display all the fields. And later you could wire up actions to those control that you need.

Comment: The logout part needs to do some work before logging out so I can't just keep it static. I need a tableviewcontroller to perform the operation before logging out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a condition for how to handle each different section within the table view.

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Edit Profile";
}else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Invite";
}else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Log out";
}......
```

Comment: Thanks man. indexPath.section that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tableView delegate methods:

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

(IF you're wanting to label the section headers and not the cells in the sections themselves)